# In this makefile, why is the prerequisite for the target "bunzip2/data2.tar" always being remade?

Tags: makefile, compression, bzip2, xz

I have a make file that is always re-running a rule despite the prerequisite being up-to-date:

```
data.tar.bz2: data.tar
    bzip2 --keep data.tar

# The following rule always runs the rule for its prerequisite
# even if it is up-to-date. Note that it doesn't matter whether
# the bunzip2 directory exists or not. I suppose is has something
# to do with the dir/file naming of the rule but I haven't been
# able to decipher why.
bunzip2/data2.tar: data.tar.bz2
    mkdir bunzip2 && cd bunzip2 && bzip2 -ckd ../data.tar.bz2 > data2.tar && cd ..

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f data.tar.bz2
    rm -Rf bunzip2
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard POSIX system calls that set timestamps on files do not support sub-second accuracy.  In order for these tools to set a specific time on a file (which they try to do so that the compressed file has the same timestamp as the original file) and preserve the original accuracy they need to use different system calls; apparently they don't do so.

What you can do to work around this is change your rule like this:

```
data.tar.bz2: data.tar
        bzip2 --keep data.tar && touch $@
```

so that the timestamp of the target is set to "now".

*ETA* The traditional system call for setting modification times on files is [utime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utime.html) which accepts timestamps only in increments of one second.  Newer versions of the POSIX spec introduced [utimensat()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/futimens.html) which allows nanosecond timestamp settings.  There is also `utimes()` which allows microsecond accuracy but which has been considered "legacy" for a long time now.

If this behavior exists in the current latest release of `bzip2`, I would consider it a bug worthy of a bug report to them.

Comment: Yep. Touch was my workaround after I discovered the issue. Thanks for mentioning POSIX.

Comment: I'm running Debian Wheezy. For what it's worth, I have bzip2 v1.0.6, lzip v1.13 (with lunzip v1.1), and unxz 5.1.0alpha. Seems as if bzip2 v1.0.6 (from 2010!) *is* [the current release](http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html) while lzip (v1.16) and xz (v5.2.1) are not.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to define a new tag but if you could add "lzip" as a tag to this question, that'd be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Something is missing from the example - but the process for analysis is the same, regardless: you can use the debug feature of make to see what rules it uses, e.g.,

```
make -d
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out what was going on here.

Using @Thomas Dickey advice to try `make -d`, it was saying that the file `data.tar.bz2` was newer than `data.tar` itself. That seems silly because the former is created from the later. But using `ls --full-time` shows bzip2 archive seems use the timestamp of the source file but it also *truncates it* after the second place. In my case, the timestamp `2015-03-12 09:32:02.452091888` was getting truncated to `2015-03-12 09:32:02.000000000` which makes it appear to be newer than the source. (By truncate I mean that `2015-03-12 13:10:29.681793152` goes to `2015-03-12 13:10:29.000000000`... it does not round up even in that case) Seems like bzip needs to bump the accuracy of their timestamps.

It appears that `lunzip` also truncates the timestamp and `unxz` preserves the original timestamp while `gzip` uses the current time. In other words, be careful with your makefiles when using compression utilities because they handle things differently.